# Excel ADODB connection for SQL runtime error

Tags: sql, excel, runtime-error, adodb, vba

I was trying to use SQL queries to work with my excel sheets as tables. I wrote the following code:

```
Global objConn As ADODB.Connection
Global ConnString As String 
Global SQL As String
Global objRS As ADODB.Recordset
Global masterFile As String

Public Sub XL_DB_connect()

Set objConn = New ADODB.Connection

masterFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & ThisWorkbook.Name

ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
             "Data Source=" & masterFile & ";" & _
             "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;" & _
             "HDR=Yes;"";"

objConn.ConnectionString = ConnString  
objConn.Open

End Sub


Public Sub executeQuery()

objRS.Source = SQL
objRS.ActiveConnection = objConn   
objRS.Open

End Sub



Public Sub XL_DB_relMem()

Set objRS = Nothing
Set objConn = Nothing
SQL = vbNullString

End Sub


Public Sub test()

Set objRS = New ADODB.Recordset
objRS.CursorLocation = adUseClient

SQL = "select PatientGID, count(LOT) from [Sheet1$] group by PatientGID"

Debug.Print SQL
Call XL_DB_connect
Call executeQuery

objRS.MoveFirst

Range("Output").Resize(10, 2).ClearContents
Range("Output").CopyFromRecordset objRS  

End Sub
```

Sheet1 has the following columns starting from cell A1
patientGID
progression 
loT 
newLoT
loTFdate
actualRegimen
loTRegimenClass 
progressionClass
pERMetFlag

On running the code, I get following error:

> "Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
>
> 'Sheet1$' is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include
>   invalid characters and punctuation and that it is not too long"

Comment: This is fine & does what you think, you would only see this error if the sheet was not actually called `Sheet1`, are you sure it is?  (Your test leaved the connection open btw)

Comment: I am sure it's called that. Is there any other thing that I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: You probably want `Set objRS.ActiveConnection = objConn`

Comment: In which subroutine ? XL_DB_relMem() ?

Comment: It works for me as expected (Excel 2016). Try renaming the sheet in both places and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today. I found that the reason was the excel file was in its read-only status. When I saved it in another location, the error was immediately fixed.